# requests и другие модули

Tags: python, модули

Допустим я прохожу авторизацию по модулю для steam(Не requests)
Я прошел авторизацию,смогу ли я потом получить данные при помощи requests?
выглядит примерно так:

```
client = Steamclient(api)
client.login(username, password, path)
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Что это за модуль, подскажите.

Comment: Если ваш Steamclient использует requests и вы сможете достать из client session, то да. Именно так, как написали это вы, если для доступа к этой странице вы должны быть авторизованы, страницу вы не получите.